# Adding a prerequisite for a list of gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp

The following tasks will run in parallel (which is fine):

```
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'lint', 'test']);
```

But I want a prerequisite task `'clean'` to run before any of them start. How can I achieve this without modifying each of the subtasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, for speed reasons the tasks will attempt to run in parallel. If you truly need something to run first to completion (like clean), then you need to use runSequence. I will make some example code here:

```
  var gulp = require('gulp'),
      runSequence = require('run-sequence');

  function runAllTasks(cb) {
    runSequence('pretasks', 'posttask', cb);
  }
  gulp.task('pretasks', ['clean']);
  gulp.task('posttask', ['build', 'lint', 'test']);
  gulp.task('default', runAllTasks);
```

The above will more or less express what you need to do. Use run sequence to run clean (or anything else that can run parallel to clean) *first*. Then, do everything after clean. Assign default to this sequential model.

Of course, running in sequence should be avoided as much as possible for performance!

Edit:

I wanted to add, since I looked at your code....

You might build *then* serve/test. You don't want to start running the server or the test runner while you are still moving files around, concatenating scripts and so on....